# Fastlane Beta: Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find CFPropertyList-3.0.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-pilot, fastlane-gym

Running fastlane beta and getting this error:

```
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find CFPropertyList-3.0.0 in any of the sources
```

I tried installing the gem through the terminal, adding it to my gemfile, updating my fastlane version... no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Same here. No Idea how to solve this, even a repo update didn't help.

Answer (score 31):

try

```
gem install CFPropertyList
```

update "You don't have write permissions for the ..."

```
sudo gem install CFPropertyList
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: Thank. I will try to explain.

Answer (score 5):

I date with it error on cocoapods plugin:

[image]

I tried install CFPropetyList-3.0.0 manualy - not help, I did updates for all gems - no help.

Helped only: `fastlane install_plugins` command, it's updated cocoapods plugin for fastlane and now worked fine.

P.S. This error start to show after update to Mojave OS.

Answer (score 4):

Update all gems:
**sudo gem update --system**

if this leads you to some error like:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
            Operation not permitted @ rb_sysopen - 
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/gem
```

Try running command:
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

This will remove this error `Could not find CFPropertyList-3.0.0 in any of the sources`

If you get error like this with `bundle install` while uploading you mobile app then go inside of the android/ios folder and run command:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my Ruby version :

1. Install rvm (if you don't have it) `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash`
2. install latest ruby (3.0.0p0) `rvm install ruby@latest` and set it as default `rvm use ruby-3.0.0 --default`
3. A few times install cocoapods `gem install cocoapods`
4. `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

enter in ios folder => cd ios

then run =>  gem install CFPropertyList